# Customize or apply conditions on <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list" value="any string"> in struts2

Tags: struts2

This tag works for when associated list is empty or null.  Can we make it to work only for empty list and not for null?  I have placed this tag in `.properties` file.

These are known as display tags:

```
<display: setProperty> tag is a struts tag used under 
<display:table name="someList"> 
<display:table>
```

Comment: What is a display prefix tag?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.However, <display: setProperty> tag is a struts tag used under <display:table name="someList"> <display:table>. These are known as display tags.

Comment: Show a full page.

Comment: I cannot do that..